# Dynamic code generation and execution without writing code to database

Tags: abap

Is it possible to generate ABAP code and execute it in memory without writing code to DB?

Comment: @fabiopagoti I cant generate inmemory programm and execute it and but problem solved. thank you

Comment: By all means edit the question so that it makes sense and also answer the question with your own solution to help people.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins actually, I have nothing to add here. I pressed reopen only because I dont like `closed as not a real question` on this question. Actually I asked about possibility of code execution without writing it into DB. And That was actually writen in the question. in SAP, code writen into DB in table REPOSRC and finally activated. After that it can be executed. But this is technology details and question should not  discuss SAP platform. I asked only that I asked. The Question looks complete for me :)

Comment: casperOne closed this question not me, but I cannot reopen it while it remains in it's current state. Plus supply sample code and examples of solutions you have tried. One sentence is too small for a question like this. The question needs to be very specific to a real-life programming issue you are experiencing, and the answer needs to specifically address it. Without being specific, the question is too broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPGENERATE_SUBROUTINE_POOL.htm). Use Google. Use Google. Use Google. Use Google. Use Google. (I have to write at least 30 characters although I really don't have anything else to say besides that wanting to generate code dynamically is usually a sign you're on the wrong track.)

Comment: Or trying to avoid security controls...

Comment: Thank you! Google is amazing thing, but sometimes wrong request won't let me go